# Responsive - White space to the Right and CSS not updating straight away (Android)

Tags: android, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I've started working on a responsive site for my company (ghd.ecommerceit.co.uk) however on an Android Phone (Samsung Note 2) there is white space to the right. for the life of me, I cannot see why it's causing this?

but also, the css changes I make does not update instantly on my phone. I have to wait sometimes half and hour.

I tried - overflow-x:hidden; but doesn't seem to work. iPhones does not display a white space to the right however I am unable to scale? so the responsive somewhere is corrupt..

Thanks

Mayur

Comment: Just another one, the description below is non responsive? I do not know what is causing this?

Comment: Bump... anyone please?